# successful build in heroku but Application error

Tags: node.js, github, heroku, heroku-cli

i'v noticed that this question been asked before but none of them covers my problem.

anyway i'v deployed a node.js project to heroku using the Heroku CLI , and it works 100%.

later on I linked it to GitHub and wanted to deploy it using GitHub , deploy was successful but the application giving an error.

- I gitignored the node_modules , db and config just incase and that needed to be said.
- I'v restarted all dynos
- repo is set on private in GitHub
  any ideas please ?

```html
2021-06-12T08:01:52.352038+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-06-12T08:01:52.352203+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2021-06-12T08:01:52.352360+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the l6_13_04@1.0.0 start script.
2021-06-12T08:01:52.352478+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-06-12T08:01:52.363711+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-06-12T08:01:52.363960+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-06-12T08:01:52.364068+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-06-12T08_01_52_353Z-debug.log
2021-06-12T08:01:52.467709+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-06-12T08:01:52.554484+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-12T08:28:17.040842+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mapetme.herokuapp.com request_id=bac4c71c-e9a9-4df1-82d3-30049c040f7f fwd="109.253.222.209" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-12T08:32:34.601328+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mapetme.herokuapp.com request_id=b28e1630-8739-44a1-8bab-50b6347b91e7 fwd="109.253.222.209" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-12T08:32:44.055618+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-12T08:32:46.496214+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-06-12T08:32:48.862282+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-06-12T08:32:48.862304+00:00 app[web.1]: > l6_13_04@1.0.0 start /app
2021-06-12T08:32:48.862305+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app
2021-06-12T08:32:48.862305+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439470+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439537+00:00 app[web.1]:   return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439539+00:00 app[web.1]:                  ^
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439540+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439541+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439542+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:18)
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439543+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439543+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439543+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439544+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439544+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439544+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439545+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439545+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439545+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439546+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439546+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439546+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/users.js:2:16)
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439546+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439547+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-06-12T08:32:49.439547+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-06-12T08:32:49.453105+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-06-12T08:32:49.453413+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-06-12T08:32:49.458918+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! l6_13_04@1.0.0 start: `node app`
2021-06-12T08:32:49.459026+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-06-12T08:32:49.459155+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2021-06-12T08:32:49.459250+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the l6_13_04@1.0.0 start script.
2021-06-12T08:32:49.459341+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-06-12T08:32:49.464221+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-06-12T08:32:49.464367+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-06-12T08:32:49.464451+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-06-12T08_32_49_460Z-debug.log
2021-06-12T08:32:49.523466+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-06-12T08:32:49.596420+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-06-12T08:32:49.622795+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-06-12T08:32:52.222185+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-06-12T08:32:54.529651+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-06-12T08:32:54.529669+00:00 app[web.1]: > l6_13_04@1.0.0 start /app
2021-06-12T08:32:54.529669+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app
2021-06-12T08:32:54.529670+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075602+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075622+00:00 app[web.1]:   return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075631+00:00 app[web.1]:                  ^
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075632+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075633+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075634+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:18)
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075635+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075635+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075635+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075636+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075636+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075636+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075637+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075637+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075637+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075638+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075638+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075638+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/users.js:2:16)
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075639+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075639+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-06-12T08:32:55.075639+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-06-12T08:32:55.095077+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-06-12T08:32:55.095371+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-06-12T08:32:55.102335+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! l6_13_04@1.0.0 start: `node app`
2021-06-12T08:32:55.102427+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-06-12T08:32:55.102549+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2021-06-12T08:32:55.102638+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the l6_13_04@1.0.0 start script.
2021-06-12T08:32:55.102723+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-06-12T08:32:55.108249+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-06-12T08:32:55.108497+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-06-12T08:32:55.108632+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-06-12T08_32_55_103Z-debug.log
2021-06-12T08:32:55.200979+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-06-12T08:32:55.265806+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: It seems the error is related to bcrypt module.

Comment: yeah but it worked previously and nothing new was added. well at least not bycrypt

Answer (score 0):

try making the repo to public and check it works or not

Comment: I'v done something better , I'v uploaded another node.js project to GitHub , public repo.
made a new app in Heroku , linked it together and same thing application error.
I think it might be something with package.json that can solve this...

Answer (score 0):

after trying a bunch of more solutions on the internet.
only deleting the node_modules and pretty much initializing everything fixed it for me.